# Default folders that are created in gwt project

Tags: gwt

I am new to gwt..While creating project its showing me default folders and packages like- t1(package created by client),t1.CLIENT,t1.SERVER,t1.SHARED package etc..
Can anybody tell what is used in which case and its usefulness ??
Also can anybody tell what is WAR folder for ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about starting by reading the documentation?

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects#DevGuideDirectoriesPackageConventions